# No disk space on / (Debian Jessie)

Tags: debian, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, du

I have a problem with disk space on my dedicated server. I have no disk space available on partition /

```
root@server1:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        96G   96G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  504K   13G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            37G     0   37G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md2        301G   65G  221G  23% /srv
```

When I mount /dev/root to /srv/checkmount and check size this partition

```
root@server1:/srv# du -h /srv/checkmount/
```

Then command returns:

```
11G     /srv/checkmount/
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: This is quire simple really, identify files that you don't need and delete them.

Comment: But you don't understand. On / I have ONLY 11G, but df -h and system detect 96G/96G..

Comment: You appear to have some non-standard config what does your `/etc/fstab` look like?